# When to Use Indeed

Tags: word-usage, indian-english

How should the word "indeed" be used? I know what it means, but I don't know when it should be used.

For example:

> "You are such a good person indeed"

Is this usage correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idiomatically, "indeed" is often used as an emphasis, particularly for sincerity. If you suspect that the listener might respond with either humility or doubt, you might add "indeed" to emphasize your sincerity.

In this sense, synonyms might include "honestly" or "truthfully", or phrases such as "I mean it" or "I'm not just saying that."

Answer (score 2):

"Indeed" is used as agreeing with someone.
It usually comes at the beginning of a sentence when I hear it.

> Indeed, he is the mayor.
>
> Indeed, you are such a good person.

The way I wrote the sentence sounds better to my ear, and it is used more commonly that way. In the context you are using, you might reply that way if a person asks if they are a good person. It's like agreeing that they are a good person.